# Trait bound not satisfied in function argument

Tags: rust, traits, avr, hal

I'm running into an issue with trait bounds and can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm working with the [arduino-uno](https://rahix.github.io/avr-hal/arduino_uno/index.html) crate from avr-hal and I have a function that reads the ADC, implemented as follows:

```
fn read_signal<T: avr_hal_generic::hal::adc::Channel<board::adc::Adc, ID = u8>>(
    adc: &mut board::adc::Adc,
    pinA0: &mut T,
) {
    let x = adc.read(&mut pinA0);
}
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
the trait bound `&mut T: avr_hal_generic::embedded_hal::adc::Channel<arduino_uno::adc::Adc>` is not satisfied
required because of the requirements on the impl of `arduino_uno::prelude::_embedded_hal_adc_OneShot<arduino_uno::adc::Adc, _, &mut T>` for `arduino_uno::adc::Adc` rustc(E0277)
```

I have tried using `where` instead, but that doesn't help. How can I fix this?

Also, though I show this specific example, I would really appreciate an explanation or pointers to better documentation on this subject/error as I've encountered it a few times and struggle to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error says:

> the trait bound `&mut T: avr_hal_generic::embedded_hal::adc::Channel<arduino_uno::adc::Adc>` is not satisfied

Notice that the error is asking for `&mut T` to implement `Channel`, `&mut T: Channel<...>`, whereas your `T` has the bound `T: Channel<...>` — applying to `T` itself rather than `&mut T`. That's why the bound you've already written isn't helping.

Now, what's the right fix? If I look at the docs you linked, I can find the type of `<Adc as OneShot>::read`. (Note: I copied the text from the *docs* to construct this snippet; I didn't read the source code.)

```rust
impl<WORD, PIN> OneShot<Adc, WORD, PIN> for Adc
where
    WORD: From<u16>,
    PIN: Channel<Adc, ID = MUX_A>,       // <---- look here
{
    pub fn read(
        &mut self,
        _pin: &mut PIN                   // <---- look here
    ) -> Result<WORD, ...>
}
```

So, `read` should be given an `&mut PIN` and the type variable `PIN` should implement `Channel`. That all sounds reasonable, *but* in your code the compiler thinks we want `&mut T` to implement `Channel`. An extra `&mut` has appeared. Where did it come from? You wrote:

```rust
fn read_signal<T: avr_hal_generic::hal::adc::Channel<board::adc::Adc, ID = u8>>(
    adc: &mut board::adc::Adc,
    pinA0: &mut T,
) {
    let x = adc.read(&mut pinA0);
}
```

`pinA0` is of type `&mut T`, but you then wrote `adc.read(&mut pinA0)`, which means the parameter to `read()` is of type `&mut &mut T`. Since `read` wants `&mut` of something implementing `Channel`, this results in the error you saw, asking for `&mut T: Channel`.

The fix, then, is to not take `&mut` of `&mut`:

```rust
    let x = adc.read(pinA0);
```

---

Under some circumstances, Rust provides [implicit coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html) which will, in particular, turn a reference to a reference (or a reference to a 'smart pointer' type implementing `Deref`) into a reference. This is why you might have had extraneous `&` or `&mut` work in the past. However, these coercions are not applied when there isn't a single concrete type that's expected, such as in this case where the function parameter's type contains the type variable `T`.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! That indeed fixed the issue (ID should be MUX_A instead of u8 in my function declaration, but that's obvious). Regarding your final point about implicit coercions, I realised my problem was confusion between declaring a variable as `mut` and declaring an argument as `&mut`, and implicit coercion may have been masking this. I think that should clear up some of the issues!